# ASP.Net Core 1.1 - Migration Failure

Tags: asp.net-core, migration

I know VS 2017 is only RC but there seem to be some major issues with migrating an ASP.Net Core 1.0 project to 1.1.  The migration tool fails converting 2 of my 8 projects in the solution (I prefer to adopt a layered architectural approach for my projects) the sample project is located [here](https://github.com/napalm684/ReciPiBookCore).  One project in particular is the class library I moved my web api controller methods into.  In trying to re-create this class library it doesn't seem one is able to declare a controller class after installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc nuget.  It is installed but the compiler is not finding the Controller, RouteAttribute classes, etc. The same issue occured with trying to setup a DI layer IServiceCollection.  Nuget Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection doesn't seem to be doing it.

The migration log quite honestly isn't really helping me.  It seems to indicate an issue with my service project and the project.json file but as you can tell it is in the repository.

It feels like Microsoft is forcing us down the path of cramming all the "web" stuff into a single project file.  Maybe these tools aren't far enough along yet but an RC would indicate they should be closer to ship ready?

> ReciPiBook.Api
>       Message
>       src\ReciPiBook.Api\ReciPiBook.Api.xproj: Failed to migrate XProj project ReciPiBook.Api. 'dotnet migrate -s -p "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ReciPiBook2017\ReciPiBookCore\src\ReciPiBook.Api" -x "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ReciPiBook2017\ReciPiBookCore\src\ReciPiBook.Api\ReciPiBook.Api.xproj"' exited with error code 1.
>       src\ReciPiBook.Api\ReciPiBook.Api.xproj: Could not find file 'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ReciPiBook2017\ReciPiBookCore\src\ReciPiBook.Services\project.json'. Migration failed.
>       src\ReciPiBook.Api\ReciPiBook.Api.xproj: Backing up C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ReciPiBook2017\ReciPiBookCore\src\ReciPiBook.Api\ReciPiBook.Api.xproj to C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ReciPiBook2017\ReciPiBookCore\Backup\src\ReciPiBook.Api\ReciPiBook.Api.xproj.
>       src\ReciPiBook.Api\project.json: Backing up C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ReciPiBook2017\ReciPiBookCore\src\ReciPiBook.Api\project.json to C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ReciPiBook2017\ReciPiBookCore\Backup\src\ReciPiBook.Api\project.json.

Comment: I have a similar (or maybe the same) problem with converting projects. However, according to the migration log, the conversion process is trying to locate project.json files for regular class libraries that I have referenced from the .NET core project. This is due to the fact that I'm currently only hosting an ASP.NET Core web api while building the code in class libraries targeting .NET 4.6.1 in order to be able to test with NCrunch.

Comment: Maybe related: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/2446/migrate-aspnet-core-existing-app.html

Comment: Issue opened with Dotnet cli https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4770

Answer (score 0):

I can't directly speak to VS2017 as I'm staying away from it as even though it's a RC, the core tooling is in ALPHA. The VS 2015 core tooling is at least in a "RC" state (actually only preview).

In VS2015 I migrated from 1.0.x to 1.1 manually (per https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-1-1/):

1. Download the 1.1 sdk
2. Change your global.json "sdk":{"version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"} (yes it's a different version string).
3. Update all the project.json package versions from 1.0 to 1.1 (some are preview some arn't). Just open up the nuget package manager, allow preview versions, then install all the updates.
4. Fix any of your project.json tool entries as the package manager clobbers those.